# Example of Android style toggle button implementation in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, togglebutton

```
<Style x:Key="AndroidToggleBtnStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border x:Name="outborder"
                        Padding="0"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderColorBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        CornerRadius="10">
                    <Border x:Name="backgrd"
                            Padding="0"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            CornerRadius="10">
                        <Border x:Name="inercircle"
                                Width="20"
                                Height="20"
                                Margin="5,0,5,0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Background="{StaticResource BorderColorBrush}"
                                CornerRadius="100">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="outborder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BackColorBlueBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="backgrd" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackColorBlueBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="inercircle" Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                        <Setter TargetName="inercircle" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackColorWhiteBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image]

It is defined and used as a style code.
When Ischecked, the background color changes.
However, there is a slight gap between the outborder and backgrd.
How can we fill in the blanks?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide `StaticResources` for the brushes, so I picked ones, but as I understand your question is, how to avoid white gaps between `outborder` and `backgrd` `Borders`

[image: Old backgrd]

You can fix it by slightly modifying `backgrd Border` so it'll cover the white gaps but still won't extend over `outborder Border`.

```
<Border x:Name="backgrd"
        Margin="0,-1,0,-1"
        Background="Transparent"
        CornerRadius="8">
```

[image: New backgrd]

On the example, I intentionally changed `outborder` `BorderBrush` to `Red` to show the difference.